# Java EE: Print pdf on the fly 

Tags: pdf, web-applications, jakarta-ee, printing

In my web application (Java EE), I would like to print a pdf file generated on the server side
on the fly in the client side without opening it. The files could be one or many. Is this possible?

Comment: Similar question (with answers!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504283/in-java-web-application-how-to-print-server-file-from-client-side

Answer (score 3):

I think it is not possible, except if you require clients to install a special application first.

Not just Java EE, it would be the same with any server-side technology.

Answer (score 0):

You either need an additional Java library or to pass it to native code. There is a blog article with some suggestions at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/